# Xamarin.Forms Android when save the image to device gallery getting access denied exception without enable storage permission in device

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-permissions, save-image

#### Description

When saving a image to device gallery without enabling the storage permission in device getting access denied exception but set read and write storage permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

#### Code

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
           ...
```

[C#]

```
var file = new Java.IO.File(
 OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures)
   .ToString());

var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(file.ToString(), "Image" + 
  DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + "." + format);

 var save = new Runnable(() =>
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew))
                {
                        bitmap?.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 97, fileStream);
                    
                }
                ...
            });
```

#### Expected Behavior

Have to save the image in device gallery without enabling the storage permission in device.

#### Actual Behavior

Getting access denied exception when save the image

#### Basic Information

VS 2019
Tested device: Lenovo A7010a48
XF version: 4.8

Answer (score 1):

You can use nuget [Xam.Plugin.Media](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Media) to achieve this function,which is a simple cross platform plugin to take photos and video or pick them from a gallery from shared code.

You can refer to the following code in xamarin forms:

```
    private async void BtnCam_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            
            var photo = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions()
            {
                DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Rear,
                Directory = "Xamarin",
                SaveToAlbum = true
            });
            
            if (photo != null)
                imgCam.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return photo.GetStream(); });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message.ToString(), "Ok");
        }
    }
```

Note: here we can set parameter `SaveToAlbum`  to `true`,then the picture will save to gallary.

In android platform,we should add `permission` and `FileProvider` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.parallelcodes.XamCam" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="XamCam">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.parallelcodes.XamCam.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Note:file `file_paths` is a file in folder `Resources/xml`.

file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
  <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```

**Note:**

1.For more detail,you can enter keywords `Xamarin Forms – Using Camera and Save Image to Gallery` in your browser to find relative article, and there is also a full sample included in above article.

2.For more about  `MediaPlugin`,you can check: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin